# Showing that following is not a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following 8 axioms for a Vector Space and the following question. 
[image]

[image]

I managed to prove that Axiom 3 doesn't work(and as a result Axiom 4 because 0 element doesn't exist) but the answer key also states that Axiom 6 doesn't work. I am having some trouble proving that. Can someone help ?

Comment: The second coordinate of the RHS will always be 0, but, on the LHS it may not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\mathbf{x} = (1,1)$ and $\alpha = \beta = 1$, we have
$$(\alpha+\beta) \circ \mathbf{x} = (1+1) \circ (1,1) = 2\circ (1,1) = (2\cdot1,2\cdot1)=(2,2)$$
On the other hand. we have
$$\alpha \circ \mathbf{x} = 1 \circ (1,1) = (1\cdot1,1\cdot1)=  (1,1) = \beta \circ \mathbf{x}$$
$$\alpha \circ \mathbf{x} \oplus \beta \circ \mathbf{x}  = (1,1)\oplus(1,1) = (1+1,0)=(2,0)$$